# Linker error when compiling assembly

Tags: assembly

I am trying to generate assembly language listing for a simple hello world program

I ran `gcc -S file.c`

and generated the file.s.

I am using the below script using the .s file generated:

```
#!/bin/bash -x

NAME=file1

for i in *.s; do
        as -o ${i%.s}.o $i
done
ld -static -o $NAME *.o
objdump -D $NAME
```

When i use this , I get an error:

```
In function `main':
(.text+0x16): undefined reference to `printf'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're not linking with the C runtime, so it can't find the `printf` function.

Comment: you need to link to `libc.so.6` dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

compile with `gcc -fverbose-asm -S -Wall` (and perhaps also `-O` or `-O2`)

<sup>The `-fverbose-asm` generates some helpful comments in the assembler.</sup>

Use `gcc -v` to understand how is the program linked. You need startup code (like some `crt0.o`) and you need to link the `libc.so.6` or `libc.a` at least.

<sup>When compiling and linking with `gcc -v` the intermediate steps, and the implicit object files and libraries, are shown. `gcc` is just starting other programs like `cc1` (the compiler proper) and `as` (assembler) and `ld` linker. Sometimes `collect2` is a sort of linker.</sup>

BTW, you could write some assembly code and use it thru `gcc`. For instance, code just one routine in assembly, and the rest in C. Then run `gcc -v -Wall routine.s main.c -o prog`

Read also the [Linux Assembly HowTo](http://asm.sourceforge.net/howto/Assembly-HOWTO.html).

Comment: Thanks Basile and Daowen. Since i am new to c coding and assembly language, I am confused where i should add the ld statement.. is it in the script file or should I link it along with the gcc stament when the .s file is generated?

Comment: I suggest to avoid writing a full program in assembly. Code just one routine in assembly. And remember, for real size (even small) programs, an optimizing compiler does better than you can do.